# Xcode - Strange Code Coverage of Swift Computed Property

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have enabled **code coverage** for my unit tests, but for one struct I can't quite hit 100%, even though I believe I am testing all possible code paths.

My struct has a computed property defined as:

```
var nativeSize: CGSize {
    if rotated {
        return targetRect.size.rotated
    } else {
        return targetRect.size
    }
}
```

(Here, `targetRect` is a stored property of the same struct, of type `CGRect`, `self.rotated` is a stored boolean property, and `self.size.rotated` is a computed property in an extension to `CGSize` that simply returns a copy with `width` and `height` interchanged)

My unit test code creates two instances of the struct, one with `rotated` set to `true` and another with it set to `false`, and accesses this `nativeSize` property in each (to cover both code paths), asserting their equaities to the expected values.

However, I only get 95.5% coverage for the struct. On the code editor, it is highlighted like this:

[image]

*(this is the only red region in the whole source file)*

**Is this an Xcode bug, or am I missing anything else?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why this line is not covered? Xcode code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257591/why-this-line-is-not-covered-xcode-code-coverage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's a **bug**.

I reproduced your code in Xcode 10.2, and I'm getting the same behaviour.

[image]

But if I change the syntax to an equivalent one-liner, the coverage goes to 100%.

[image]

I suggest you open a radar. I'll be doing the same.