# Why this line is not covered? Xcode code coverage

Tags: swift, xcode, code-coverage, xctest

I'm experiencing an issue with the report of code coverage in Xcode.
As you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

On the left tab, line 58 is "touched" from the break-point, and on the right tab, the test passes. While on the right tab, I'm running only the test on line 37.

Why does Xcode sign the line 58 in red, as not covered?

Line 53 is not "touched" (if I set a break-point there).
Using SQLite as a database.

The entire project is available [here](https://github.com/DanielZanchi/Internship-SwiftTDD).

**EDIT**: Adding code:

Test.swift

```
func testAddFuelFail() {
  fuelsManager.dropTable()
  XCTAssertEqual(addFuel(), -1)
}
```

FuelsManager.swift

```
func addFuel(dateOfFuel: Date, mileageOnSave: Int, quantityOfFuel: Double, pricePerUnitOfFuel: Double) -> Int64 {
  let insertFuel = fuelsTable.insert(date <- dateOfFuel, mileage <- mileageOnSave, quantity <- quantityOfFuel, pricePerUnit <- pricePerUnitOfFuel)
  do {
    let id = try database!.run(insertFuel)
      return id
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
  return -1
}
```

Comment: In regard to the question, how can we know what `database` is and how the `run` method is defined or what the `dropTable` does? I can only assume `run` returns -1 when something goes wrong rather than generating an error or that Xcode code coverage is broken

Comment: If the breakpoint is touched, that means that the return value is "-1", also means that the line is covered. why is Xcode reporting it as not covered?

Comment: Ah, I didn't get the part about "touched" but if line 51 is not touched then an error must have happened earlier which only leaves `let insertFuel = ...` which doesn't make much sense. Have you tried using print statements rather than break points to track what is happening?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just uploaded a new image with the print statements.

Comment: Are you running tests with optimizations?

Comment: @Sulthan if you mean the "new build system", YES. But I get the same issue if I use  the Legacy build system

Comment: Are you importing your code using `@testable`?

Comment: yes! @testable import ProjectName

Comment: I don't understand why the error isn't printed in your last example. Wild guess but what about cleaning and rebuilding everything?

Comment: The error gets printed. I filtered the output. The strange thing is that line 57 gets printed but not covered from code coverage.

Comment: For me it looks like a bug in the code coverage tool.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is `<-`? I've never seen the arrow that way around... Is it a custom operator I assume?

Comment: I'm upvoting just for the purple breakpoints :-)

Answer (score 4):

Actually its a bug reported [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9145?jql=text%20~%20%22code%20coverage%22).

> 1. Coverage number varies between multiple runs on XC 10 on the same binary. Like in first run it shows x% vs in another run it will show y% keeping the same code.
> 2. Coverage number/Number of tests varies while running on 11.4 simulator and 12.0 simulator, both ran  on XC 10
> 3. Number of tests also a little different like in some run it was 5507 tests vs in some runs it was 5506.

XC 10 certainly came with lots of bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Take the breakpoint out and run the test. Once the test has finished running the coverage information should change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but even without the breakpoint the code doesn’t get covered.